# javascript number guessing game is outputting random information

Tags: javascript, random, terminal, output

I'm trying to create a game that randomly picks a number between 1 and 10. The problem is that for some reason, when I compile the code, the program outputs all this extra data and I can't seem to figure out why it's doing it. Can I please have some help? Below is all my code.

I'm using Replit

```
var readline = require('readline');

var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
var lives = 5;

var terminal = readline.createInterface(
{
  input : process.stdin,
  output : process.stdout
});

terminal.setPrompt('Guess the number! (0-10): ');
terminal.prompt();
terminal.on('line', function(answer)
{
  var answerNum = parseInt(answer);

  if (answerNum > randomNumber)
  {
    console.log('Too high!');
    console.log('You have '+lives+' lives left');
  }

  else if (answerNum < randomNumber)
  {
    console.log('Too low!');
    console.log('You have '+lives+' lives left');
  }

  else if (answerNum === randomNumber)
  {
    console.log('W I N N E R ! ! !');
    console.log('You lost only '+ (6-lives) + ' lives');
    process.exit(0);
  }

  else
  {
    console.log("That wasn't a number I recognise");
    console.log('You have '+lives+' lives');
  }

  lives--;
  if (lives == 0)
  {
    console.log('G A M E  O V E R ! ! !');
    process.exit(0);
  }

  terminal.prompt();
});

terminal.on('close', function()
{
  console.log('C H I C K E N :P')
  process.exit(1);
});
```

this is what it's outputting

```
Guess the number! (0-10): Interface {
  _sawReturnAt: 0,
  isCompletionEnabled: true,
  _sawKeyPress: false,
  _previousKey: null,
  escapeCodeTimeout: 500,
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    close: [ [Function], [Function] ],
    '': [Function]
  },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  output: WriteStream {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: null,
      pipesCount: 0,
      flowing: null,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: false,
      sync: true,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    readable: false,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
      resize: [Function: onresize]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: [Object],
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 4,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
    },
    writable: true,
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: null,
    _server: null,
    columns: 80,
    rows: 24,
    _type: 'tty',
    fd: 1,
    _isStdio: true,
    destroySoon: [Function: destroy],
    _destroy: [Function: dummyDestroy],
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 3,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TTY { [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular] },
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
  },
  input: ReadStream {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 0,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: null,
      pipesCount: 0,
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: false,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: true,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    readable: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      pause: [Function],
      data: [Function: onData],
      keypress: [Function: onkeypress]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 0,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
    },
    writable: false,
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: null,
    _server: null,
    isRaw: true,
    isTTY: true,
    fd: 0,
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TTY { reading: false, [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular] },
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(keypress-decoder)]: StringDecoder {
      encoding: 'utf8',
      [Symbol(kNativeDecoder)]: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 01>
    },
    [Symbol(escape-decoder)]: Object [Generator] {}
  },
  historySize: 30,
  removeHistoryDuplicates: false,
  crlfDelay: 100,
  _prompt: 'Guess the number! (0-10): ',
  terminal: true,
  line: '',
  cursor: 0,
  history: [],
  historyIndex: -1,
  prevRows: 0,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kSubstringSearch)]: null,
  [Symbol(line object stream)]: undefined
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Which operating system, Node.js version and readline package version are you using?

Comment: @JosephDaSilva I'm using Replit to compile my code. Everything else is just basic out the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replit outputs the value of the last evaluated expression, which in your case is `terminal.on('close', ...)`. The function call returns the `terminal` instance, and this is the "extra" output that you are seeing.

You can solve this by adding the line `undefined;` at the end.

Comment: where do I add `undefined` exactly?

Comment: It should be the last line in your script, after the `terminal.on('close', ...)` statement.